# My function won't trigger onclick jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have an asp.net kendo grid and inside i have an element with a class. I want to replace this class with another by clicking on a link that i put on right side.

So i used jquery to do it but it's not seem to be working.. and inside the console of chrome i don't get any error. I've tried to put alert but it's not triggering.

If someone could help here is my jquery

```
function changetoOK() {
    grid.tbody.find("td").onclick(function (index) {
        if ($("a").hasClass('changeToOk'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('customClassVerif');
            $(this).addClass('customClassOK');
        }            
    });
}
```

also i add to create a fake link with an html helper to put it inside my grid so i have this in the grid :

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(@Html.EmptyLink("Passer à OK").ToHtmlString());
```

and this in a class

```
public static class MyHtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString EmptyLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText)
    {
        var tag = new TagBuilder("a");
        tag.MergeAttribute("class", "changeToOK");
        tag.MergeAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0);");
        tag.SetInnerText(linkText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

I think it could be good to know. I've made some change inside my code first and here is some explenation.

I have an element inside the grid with a class and i want that class to change to another when i click my link.

Comment: `grid.tbody.find("td").onclick` is not jQuery

Comment: Could it be that `grid` and/or `tbody` in the code above are not jQuery objects? jQuery methods, in this case `.find()`, can only be called on jQuery objects. Further your `$("a")` returns a collection of all anchor elements in the document, but you need a specific one I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you try use 'onclick' method that doesn't work in jQuery.

Try use .on('click', function(index) ...

Answer (score 0):

.onclick isn't a jquery method, try .click instead, like so:

```
function changetoOK() {
    grid.tbody.find("td").click(function (index) {
        if ($("a").hasClass('changeToOk'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('changeToOk');
            $(this).addClass('customClassOK');
        }            
    });
}
```

This will bind the click event to the `td` elements, although bear in mind all the function you've provided will do is find all `a` elements and see if any of them has the class `changeToOk`. The only reason I mention this is because you're giving the click function an index that is then never used.

Comment: Yeah i think i missed something. What i actually want is this : when i click on the a element inside the td in the grid i want that an other td element of the grid get the class customClassOK by removing the class customClassVerif (i've made an edit in my post)

Comment: So you're saying that you want to click the a element which happens to be within a td element in the grid, which will then remove customClassVerif from a different td and replace the class with customClassOk?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i want, the different td is also inside the grid

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work as expected :

function changetoOK() {
    grid.tbody.find("td").on('click', function (event) {
        if ($("a").hasClass('changeToOk'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('changeToOk');
            $(this).addClass('customClassOK');
        }            
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not working even for what it supposed to do. But i've made a little change about what i need to do on my post, also inside a comment bellow DibsyJr's answer

Comment: Could it be that `grid` and/or `tbody` in the code above are not jQuery objects? jQuery methods, in this case `.find()`, can only be called on jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone that want to do the same as me, finaly find out how.

All you have to do is this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.changeToOK', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.verifyCell').removeClass('customClassVerif').addClass('customClassOK');
})
```

I added a second class to my first element and it works !

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.